Three.js concept to render/modify Data3DTextures?
I have an existing application that renders 3D voxel densities (D) and an overlay of 3D voxel labels (L). Those are saved in two pretty large THREE.Data3DTextures.
I want to use render-to-texture to manipulate a limited area (e.g. 16x16x16) of L based on the current content of L and D. I understand, that I cannot use the Data3DTexture L as a render target, but that I need to create a new THREE.WebGL3DRenderTarget() that will create its own texture/buffer.
My current strategy:
Create a small temporary 16x16x16 WebGL3DRenderTarget patch (P) and render to it using D and L as input to the shader. Then somehow copy P to the right position in L:
P := f(L, D)
L' := P

Problem: copyTextureToTexture3D() does not take a RenderTarget as source and copyFramebufferToTexture3D() does not exist in THREE.
How do I get the data copied from P to L?
Do I have to make L a WebGL3DRenderTarget and use a copy shader to copy P? And how do I get the initial data into L, since the WebGL3DRenderTarget constructor does not take input data like Data3DTexture constructor.

Note: creating a WebGL3DRenderTarget for L in the first place and render directly to it does not work, since one cannot take L and D as input to create a new L in one shader pass (also there are memory constraints).
